# ASP.NET Azure deployment didnt produce the webpage

Tags: asp.net, azure

I am trying to deploy a ASP.NET web form into Azure App services. The project so far achieved
1. On visual studio it runs on IIS express, Load the page and when enters the data it straight goes to the SQL server.

2. I have Published the same solution into Azure App services.It says "Publish Succeeded". However, the webpage open was:[image]
3. I tried to deploy it to a folder and I see below files. i cannot find an HTML file. I can only see :[image].

Can you please someone help me to resolve this.

Comment: Um, that WebForm1.aspx *is* the page, HTML are static files, you're deploying dynamic website, so (in ASP.NET webform at least) you'll get aspx files. Also, you mentioned SQL Server, has it been deployed on Azure or at least an internet-accessible server, and has the connection string updated to connect to it?

Comment: Thanks, The data link is working correctly when i run on local machine and inserting data into Azure SQL server.

Comment: I wonder, is the page on the IIS and Azure is the same? Eg, if you get localhost:portNumber/WebForm1.aspx when running on IIS, try azuredomain/WebForm1.aspx